# Installing library on dev server without touching anything

Tags: server, wkhtmltopdf

I want to install wkhtmltopdf library inside `/home/dev` directory, and I can't touch anything else outside of this directory, because it's not my server.

The file has .deb extension, I have run in `/home/dev`:

```
$ wget "http://file-to-install.com/"
$ dpkg -x my_file.deb
```

So the file exists. Now I want to run:

```
$ dpkg -i my_file.deb
```

Which will install it, but my question is - does this install the library only inside this dev folder, without touching anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to [How to extract RPM or DEB packages](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2008/01/28/how-to-extract-rpm-or-deb-packages/), which is linked to from the [FAQ on the downloads page](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html#faq):

> `ar p wkhtmltox.deb data.tar.xz | tar zx`